# Date is not displaying correct with substr & like query

Tags: sql, hue

I am trying to get this out out, 
but i am experiencing that the substr i am using is incorrect ,

For an example , all my columns are displaying 
hdfs://asdasda/asdas/fdsfdsfd/received_files/asdasd_**20191231**_11122333_123456789_CO.dat

some of which has more character so in order for me to get the exact date in the column is inconsistent if i am using subsring

some will return 20191230
but some will return _2020123

How do we tackle this problem ?

i am trying to display only data , this is using sql language or hue , 
when i input my script in ,

```
select SUBSTR(input_file_name, LENGTH(input_file_name) - 44, 9) from th_ingestion_status limit 100
```

i feel my script for Like and substr statement is incorrect

Comment: Which database are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want the first sequence of 8 digits surrounded by underscores, use `regexp_extract()`:

```
select regexp_extract(filename, '_([0-9]{8})_', 1)
```

If you need this after the last `/`, then:

```
select regexp_extract(filename, '_([0-9]{8})_[^/]*$', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, also please mention the database you are using, so that can provide relevant query

```
substr(column_name, instr(column_name, '_', 1, 2) +1, 6)
```

**Oracle Test Case:**

```
select 'hdfs://asdasda/asdas/fdsfdsfd/received_files/asdasd_20191231_11122333_123456789_CO.dat', substr('hdfs://asdasda/asdas/fdsfdsfd/received_files/asdasd_20191231_11122333_123456789_CO.dat', instr('hdfs://asdasda/asdas/fdsfdsfd/received_files/asdasd_20191231_11122333_123456789_CO.dat', '_', 1, 2) +1, 6)
```

from dual;

Comment: Hi Jim , i have updated my question . your solution was gving error when i did in Hue

Comment: What is the database you are using. I provided the solution for oracle